# Access Denied when trying to access sub pages on static website hosted on S3

Tags: web, static, hugo

I am trying to create a static website using Hugo. I built my hugo site and uploaded the public folder to Amazon S3. After setting the CORS policy, changing the filepath for the css and js files in the index.html I was able to get my first page to render.
I already set the bucket to public.

However, I am not able to get the sub pages to render. When I click on a link to the subpages I get an access denied error.

I have tried a CloudFront deployment  
I have tried a setting the error to index.html 
I have tried changing the filename of the subfolders to something other than index.html 
I have tried setting the bucket to public

I **was** able to go directly to the index.html in the sub folder on the S3 console and view the page directly. But I was not able to navigate to any of the links. As soon as I clicked a link, I received the Access Denied message again.

### CORS Policy

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://homepage"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

### Bucket Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::homepage/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It'd be more helpful if you provided the current configuration you have.

Here are a few things to look for in the Bucket view:
1. Did you enable "Static website hosting" in the "Properties" tab?
2. Is "Block public access" set to "off" in the "Permissions" tab?
3. Does the "Bucket policy" in the "Permissions" tab, allow for "GetObject" on all resources in the bucket?
4. Does the "CORS" for all "headers" and "all origins"?

Comment: Thank you for the response Sasho. I edited post to provide info you mentioned. Block Public Access is off. Static Website hosting is enabled.

Comment: The bucket policy seems fine. I assume you changed your bucket name to "homepage" in the config.

Try changing "Allowed Origins" to "*" in the CORS config. Also, in "Allowed Methods" remove "PUT" and "POST" (you don't need them for static serving), and try to add "HEAD".

Comment: I made those changes, removed PUT POST added HEAD. Changed Allowed Origins to * and still no luck.

Comment: Make sure to use the S3 "static website hosting" link for testing, to avoid cached errors from CloudFront.
Then check these four things:
1. That the static files are in the root folder of the bucket;
2. In "static website hosting" make sure that "hosting type" is set to "Host a static website", and set the index and error document to your default HTML page (e.g. index.html);
3. In the "permissions" tab, the "permissions overview" should say "public" in yellow;
4. In the "permissions" tab, the "block public access" should have everything "disabled", all types of block should be unticked.